# Compare two zip files using KDiff3

Tags: compare, unzip, kdiff3

I have quite often to compare two zip files under Windows. Usually I unzip each of them into a temporary folder, then compare the folders with kdiff3, then delete the temporary folders.

I'm looking for a way to do this with a single step, i.e. directly tell KDiff3 to compare the two zip files, which then automatically unzipps each file and compares the content.

I guess if this may be possible with the **preprocessor command**, but the examples seem to refer to text files only.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled here as was looking for similar tool. I ended with writing this small batch to speedup the diff.

```
@echo off
if not exist %1 goto error
if not exist %2 goto error

7z x -oa %1 
7z x -ob %2 

kdiff a b
goto end


:error
echo diff-zips r1.zip r2.zip

:end
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @rostok. I too was thinking about a small Python tool to cover this, but I just haven't got around to it yet.